# Node axios not sending correct header: 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, fs, hubspot-api

I am attempting to upload a file using the Node example provided in the [HubSpot docs](https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/files/v3/upload_new_file).

I am receiving `415(Unsupported media type)`. The response says I am sending the header `application/json` even though I am setting `multipart/form-data`.

```
const uploadFile = async () => {    

    const postUrl = `https://api.hubapi.com/filemanager/api/v3/files/upload?hapikey=${HAPI_KEY}`;

    const filename = `${APP_ROOT}/src/Files/Deal/4iG_-_CSM_Additional_Capacity/test.txt`;

    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }

    var fileOptions = {
        access: 'PUBLIC_INDEXABLE',
        overwrite: false,
        duplicateValidationStrategy: 'NONE',
        duplicateValidationScope: 'ENTIRE_PORTAL'
    };

    var formData = {
        file: fs.createReadStream(filename),
        options: JSON.stringify(fileOptions),
        folderPath: '/Root'
    };

    try {
        const resp = await axios.post(postUrl, formData, headers); // API request

        console.log(resp.data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
    }
}
```

Can you see what the problem is or recommend a better way of uploading the file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Node example you link to uses the (deprecated) [`request` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), not Axios.

To use Axios ([source](https://github.com/axios/axios#form-data)) you would rewrite that as:

```
const FormData = require('form-data');
 
const form = new FormData();
form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(filename));
form.append('options', JSON.stringify(fileOptions));
form.append('folderPath', '/Root');

const config = { headers: form.getHeaders() };

axios.post(postUrl, form, config);
```

Comment: I tried that but I get the same error response. This method sets the header as ''Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' when the docs requires the header ''Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data''

Comment: @Larney — It sets the correct content type when I run that code — https://imgur.com/a/gIYo9jC — (it points at a test URL that echos the headers back). You must have missed something.

Comment: hmmm I replicated your solution and I am still getting content-type:
application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0):

We can Run API in Postman and check NodeJs - Axios Detail in Postman Code Snippet and I Think That's the Better way for this.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');

const uploadFile = async () => {
    try {
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('folderPath', '/Root');
        form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(`${APP_ROOT}/src/Files/Deal/4iG_-_CSM_Additional_Capacity/test.txt`));
        data.append('options', JSON.stringify({
            access: 'PUBLIC_INDEXABLE',
            overwrite: false,
            duplicateValidationStrategy: 'NONE',
            duplicateValidationScope: 'ENTIRE_PORTAL'
        }));
        
        var config = {
            method: 'post',
            url: `https://api.hubapi.com/filemanager/api/v3/files/upload?hapikey=${HAPI_KEY}`,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            data: data
        };
        
        const resp = await axios(config); // API request
        console.log(resp.data)
    } catch (error) {
        // error
    }
}
```